# How to align text in sequencediagram calls?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd, sequence

[image] 1. How can the text in sequencediagram calls be aligned or moved left and right? For example, in following example, how can the 1st message be moved somewhat right and message 5 and 6 be moved left to fit in one page? (I want to avoid using resizebox since it shrinks font size also). I simplified the text here, text inside shortstack is a set of equations on top of each other.

2. If sequencediagram spills over a page (vertically), it gets truncated at the bottom of the page. Is there a way, sequenediagram can span two pages?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    %   \resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{%
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \tikzstyle {inststyle}+=[bottom color=orange!5, top color=orange!5, rounded corners =1 mm]      
        \newthread  [cyan!10]   {u}   {$U_{i}$}
        \newinst                {uid} {$UID_{Ui}$}
        \newinst                {vm}  {$VM_{i}$}
        \newinst                {spc} {$sPC_{Ui}$}
        \newinst                {src} {$sRC_{Vi}$}
        \newinst                {ts}  {$TS_{i}$}
        \newinst                {rto} {$RTO$}
        \newinst                {ib}  {$IB$}
        \newinst                {as}  {$AS$}
        
        
        \begin{sdblock}{\shortstack[l]{}}{}
            \path (inst1.west) -- (inst9.east);
            
            \begin{call}{u}
                {\shortstack[l] {
                        1. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4\\
                        1. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4
                }}
                {vm}
                {\shortstack[l] {
                        \postlevel
                        2. Hello, test1 test2 test3\\
                        2. Hello, test1 test2 test3
                }}
                \begin{call}{vm}
                    {\shortstack[l] {
                        \postlevel
                        3. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6\\
                        3. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6
                    }}
                    {rto}
                    {\shortstack[l] {
                        \postlevel
                            4. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5\\
                            4. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5
                    }}
                    \begin{call}{rto}
                        {\shortstack[l] {
                        \postlevel
                            5. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7\\
                            5. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7
                        }}
                        {as}
                        {\shortstack[l] {
                        \postlevel
                                6. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4\\
                                6. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4
                        }}
                    \end{call}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
        \end{sdblock}
    \end{sequencediagram}
    \caption{SequenceDiagram1}
    \label{seqdiag}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `\shortstack`?

Comment: Actually, I simplified it here. I had quite many multiple lines on top of each other for each message for which I used shortstack

Answer (score 2):

Here the `call` environment is extended from

```tex
% from
\begin{call}[height]{caller}         {function}{callee}        {return}
% to
\begin{call}[height]{caller}[options]{function}{callee}[options]{return}
%                           ^ first new opt-arg        ^ second
```

The two new optional arguments both accept `tikz` node options which will be applied to the node having text `function` and `return`, respectively.

To further narrow down the output, I also added `\tikzset{inststyle/.append style={minimum width=1.2cm}}` right after `\begin{sequencediagram}`.

You can use different values and node options.

To the second question, no `sequencediagram`, which uses `tikzpicture`, cannot span over multiple pages.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{xpatch}

%\makeatletter
% before
%   \begin{call}[height]{caller}         {function}{callee}         {return}
%                1       2                3         4                5
% now
%   \begin{call}[height]{caller}[options]{function}{callee}[options]{return}
%                1       2       3 (new)  4<-3      5<-4    6 (new)  7<-5
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{call}{ O{1} m O{} m m O{} m }{
  \tikzset{
    umlsd/call function/.style={#3},
    umlsd/call return/.style={#6}
  }
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{#5}}
    {\begin{callself}[#1]{#2}{#4}{#7}}
    {\begin{callanother}[#1]{#2}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\f\thecallevel}{\t\thecallevel}}
  {\end{callself}}
  {\end{callanother}}
}

\xpatchcmd\callanother
  {midway, above}
  {midway, above, umlsd/call function}
  {}{\fail}

\xpatchcmd\endcallanother
  {midway, above}
  {midway, above, umlsd/call return}
  {}{\fail}

\xpatchcmd\callself
  {near start, above right}
  {near start, above right, umlsd/call function}
  {}{\fail}

\xpatchcmd\endcallself
  {midway, right}
  {midway, right, umlsd/call return}
  {}{\fail}

\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
    \tikzstyle {inststyle}+=[bottom color=orange!5, top color=orange!5, rounded corners =1 mm]
    
    % set inst node narrower
    \tikzset{inststyle/.append style={minimum width=1.2cm}} % <<< added here
    
    \newthread  [cyan!10]   {u}   {$U_{i}$}
    \newinst                {uid} {$UID_{Ui}$}
    \newinst                {vm}  {$VM_{i}$}
    \newinst                {spc} {$sPC_{Ui}$}
    \newinst                {src} {$sRC_{Vi}$}
    \newinst                {ts}  {$TS_{i}$}
    \newinst                {rto} {$RTO$}
    \newinst                {ib}  {$IB$}
    \newinst                {as}  {$AS$}
    
    
    \begin{sdblock}{\shortstack[l]{}}{}
        \path (inst1.west) -- (inst9.east);
        
        \begin{call}{u}
            % to avoid overlapping, move 5pt upward and 0pt right
            [pos=0, above right=5pt and 0pt] % <<< added here
            {\shortstack[l] {
                    1. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4\\
                    1. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4
            }}
            {vm}
            [pos=1, above right] % <<< added here
            {\shortstack[l] {
                    \postlevel
                    2. Hello, test1 test2 test3\\
                    2. Hello, test1 test2 test3
            }}
            \begin{call}{vm}
                {\shortstack[l] {
                    \postlevel
                    3. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6\\
                    3. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6
                }}
                {rto}
                {\shortstack[l] {
                    \postlevel
                        4. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5\\
                        4. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5
                }}
                \begin{call}{rto}
                    [pos=1, above left] % <<< added here
                    {\shortstack[l] {
                    \postlevel
                        5. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7\\
                        5. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7
                    }}
                    {as}
                    [pos=0, above left] % <<< added here
                    {\shortstack[l] {
                    \postlevel
                            6. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4\\
                            6. Hello, test1 test2 test3 test4
                    }}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
        \end{call}
    \end{sdblock}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update: Similar patching for `messcall` environment

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{xpatch}

%
% add opt-arg for "messcall" env
%
% before
%   \begin{messcall}[height]{caller}         {function}{callee}
%                    1       2                3         4
% now
%   \begin{messcall}[height]{caller}[options]{function}{callee}
%                    1       2       3 (new)  4<-3      5<-4
%
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{messcall}{ O{1} m O{} m m }{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \stepcounter{callevel} % push
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (cf\thecallevel) {}
  (#5.\threadbias)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (ct\thecallevel) {};
  
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] ({cf\thecallevel}) -- (ct\thecallevel)
  node[midway, above, #3] {#4};
  \def\l\thecallevel{#1}
  \def\f\thecallevel{#2}
  \def\t\thecallevel{#5}
  \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[instcolor#2]
}
{
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{\l\thecallevel}
  \path
  (\f\thecallevel)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (rf\thecallevel) {}
  (\t\thecallevel.\threadbias)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.3*\unitfactor) node (rt\thecallevel) {};
  \drawthread{ct\thecallevel}{rt\thecallevel}
  \addtocounter{callevel}{-1} % pop
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
  \newthread{t}{:Thread}
  \newinst[1]{i}{:Instance}
  \newinst[1]{a}{:Action}
  
  \begin{messcall}{t}[blue, pos=0, above right]{function1()}{i}
    \begin{messcall}{i}[red, pos=1, above left]{function2()}{a}
    \end{messcall}
  \end{messcall}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have used "call"s at many places and many of them are working fine. Will this not clash with already used "call"s. Is it possible that I can use this with already existing "call"s? How can we keep using the old version and also use the newly defined command as well?

Comment: @pba This patch is compatible with old usages, as far as the key names `/tikz/umlsd/call function`  and `/tikz/umlsd/call function` are not clashed.

Comment: That was very helpful. I am also using messcall. Can you please suggest similar thing for messcall? I will be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pba Answer updated.

Comment: Many many thanks. It was very helpful. My sincere gratitude to you spending your valuable time in helping students like me.